# Cambiar resultado nulo por un valor en SQL

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle

La siguiente consulta `sql`

```
select (sum(G325.G303MNTE) + sum(G325.G303MNTD)) as debito, G325.G303UUID as id
from GSCF325 G325
    inner join GSCF300 G300 on G300.G300UUID = G325.G303UUID
where G325.G303IMVI = 'P'
and  G325.G303DEL = ' ' and G325.G303DBCR='D' and  G300.G300CTA = 1104070196
and trunc(G325.G303FEMI) = to_Date('2019/02/13','YYYY-MM-DD')
group by G325.G303UUID
```

Me devuelve como resultado `null`, para ambos caso, tanto como para *DEBITO* y *ID*, he confirmado si el usuario existe en ambas tablas donde realizo la comparación, y si existen, pero creo que al devolver un resultado nulo, los demas campos los pone null tambien. Si es asi, tengo la duda de como cambiar los resultados `NULL` por otro valor.

Comment: Te devuelve null los sum?

Comment: @gbianchi si, me devuelve  null

Comment: Podrias usar coalesce para cambiar el null por 0

Comment: Lo raro es que dices que también el `id`es null, efectivamente es así?.

Comment: Sin conocer las tablas y sus datos, no podemos saber que está mal en la consulta. Incluye la información por favor. También podrías modificar la consulta para que solo te devuelva el ID y quitar todos los condicionales, para confirmar que si te trae información y luego agregar uno por uno los condicionales para encontrar cuál es el que no aplica y hace que la consulta devuelva null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes utilizar las funciones [`coalesce()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) e [`IsNull()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) para sustituir un valor nulo por otro.

Por ejemplo:

```
select (coalesce(sum(G325.G303MNTE), 0) + coalesce(sum(G325.G303MNTD), 0)) as debito
       , G325.G303UUID as id
  from GSCF325 G325
       left join GSCF300 G300 on G300.G300UUID = G325.G303UUID
 where G325.G303IMVI = 'P'
   and G325.G303DEL = ' ' and G325.G303DBCR='D' and  G300.G300CTA = 1104070196
   and trunc(G325.G303FEMI) = to_Date('2019/02/13','YYYY-MM-DD')
 group by G325.G303UUID
```

## `coalesce()`

En el caso de `coalesce()` que es mi preferida, por ser parte del estándar SQL (por lo que existe en muchos motores), puedes mandar *N* parámetros y la función retornará el primero que no sea nulo, por ejemplo:

```
select coalesce(campo1, campo2, campo3, campo4, campo5)
  from tabla;
```

Devolverá el valor del primer campo que no sea nulo, en el orden de entrada de los parámetros. Devolverá `null` en caso que todos sean nulos.

## `IsNull()`

IsNull es una función específica de SQL Server, que recibe dos parámetros. Similar a coalesce, devuelve el primero que no sea nulo.

```
select IsNull(campo1, campo2)
  from tabla;
```

Devolverá entonces, el valor del primer campo que no sea nulo, o `null` en caso que ambos lo sean.

Answer (score -2):

Estoy casi seguro que el problema está en que no usas lefth, right o full precedido del join, hace una pruebita a ciegas digamos con cada uno de esos tres para ver los resultados, pero deberías estudiar bien el funcionamiento ese tipo de uniones.
Acá hay algo muy resumido..: http://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/oracleya/temarios/descripcion.php?cod=207&punto=1&inicio=

Comment: Esto parece relamente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]